# Create Custom Return Error Validate in Asp Core 2.2 in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

i need to create a Create Custom Return Validate in Asp Core 2.2 in WebApi .

**First Step :**

I Create a on `OnResultExecuting` :

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
{
 if (context.Result is BadRequestObjectResult badRequestObjectResult)
        {
            var message = badRequestObjectResult.Value.ToString();
            if (badRequestObjectResult.Value is SerializableError errors)
            {
                var errorMessages = errors.SelectMany(p => (string[])p.Value).Distinct();
                message = string.Join(" | ", errorMessages);
            }
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new ReturnResult(false, ResultStatus.BadRequest, message))
            { StatusCode = badRequestObjectResult.StatusCode };
        }
}
```

**Second Step** :

i Create a `IValidatableObject` in `UserDto` :

```
 public class UserDto : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Family { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public GenderType Gender { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        foreach (var item in ValidateList.UsernameBanList)
            if (Username.Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Username Invalid", new[] { nameof(Username) });
        foreach (var item in ValidateList.PasswordBanList)
            if (Password.Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Password Invalid, new[] { nameof(Password) });
        foreach (var item in ValidateList.EmailBanList)
            if (Email.Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                yield return new ValidationResult("Email Invalid", new[] { nameof(Email) });
    }
}
```

**Third Step** :

I Create a `ReturnResult` Class :

```
public class ReturnResult
{
    public bool Success { get; }
    public ResultStatus Status { get; }
    public string Message { get; }

    public ReturnResult(bool Success, ResultStatus Status, string Message = null)
    {
        this.Success = Success;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.Message = Message ?? Status.ToDisplay();
    }

    #region implicit operator
    public static implicit operator ReturnResult(OkResult result)
    {
        return new ReturnResult(true, ResultStatus.Success);
    }

    public static implicit operator ReturnResult(BadRequestResult result)
    {
        return new ReturnResult(false, ResultStatus.BadRequest);
    }

    public static implicit operator ReturnResult(BadRequestObjectResult result)
    {
        var message = result.ToString();
        if (result.Value is SerializableError error)
        {
            var errorMessage = error.SelectMany(p => (string[])p.Value).Distinct();
            message = string.Join(" | ", errorMessage);
        }
        return new ReturnResult(false, ResultStatus.BadRequest, message);
    }

    public static implicit operator ReturnResult(ContentResult result)
    {
        return new ReturnResult(true, ResultStatus.Success, result.Content);
    }

    public static implicit operator ReturnResult(NotFoundResult result)
    {
        return new ReturnResult(false, ResultStatus.NotFound);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Now All Return in Api by this Format :**

```
{
"success": true,
"status": 0,
"message": "success process"
 }
```

in `UserDto` i Create a Validate in for Username and Password and Email then i need to return all error of them return by this format :

```
{
"success": true,
"status": 0,
"message": "Email Invalid | Password Invalid | Username Invalid"
 }
```

but it not show me by this format , it show me this format :

```
{
"success": false,
"status": 2,
"message": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidationProblemDetails"
 }
```

how can i solve this problem ????

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? I made a test with your code, and it works correctly, check [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyTSr.png). Try to debug your code line by line to see where it return `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidationProblemDetails`.

Comment: Probably badRequestObjectResult.Value.ToString() returns the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ValidationProblemDetails", and the next if condition is not executed. 
It's better to say what you wrote in the controller

Comment: I have the same code and the same result. What really caused the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try it:

```
public static implicit operator ReturnResult(BadRequestObjectResult result)
        {
            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = result.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Errors");
            Dictionary<string, string[]> errors = (Dictionary<string, string[]>)(pi.GetValue(result.Value, null));

            var message = result.ToString();
            var errorMessage = error.SelectMany(p => p.Value).Distinct();
            message = string.Join(" | ", errorMessage);
            return new ReturnResult(false, ResultStatus.BadRequest, message);
        }
```

Comment: Can you say why "result.Value is SerializableError error" doesn't recognize the result.Value as SerializableError?